# Divide column into rows mysql

Tags: mysql, split, divide

I have the following table created by the following code

```
SELECT NOME_PROGRAMA, EMISSORA,DATA,
    hora_inicio,
    hora_fim,
    CONCAT(LEFT(hora_inicio, 2), ':00') as new_inicio,
    case
    when mid(hora_fim,4,2) != "00" then CONCAT(LEFT(hora_fim, 2) +1, ':00')  else  LEFT(hora_fim,5) 
    end as new_fim,
    CONCAT(LEFT(hora_inicio, 2), ':00 - ',case
    when mid(hora_fim,4,2) != "00" then CONCAT(LEFT(hora_fim, 2) +1, ':00')  else  LEFT(hora_fim,5) 
    end)  AS TIMEBAND
FROM
    ibope.tb_audprogramas
LIMIT 100;
```

```
NOME_PROGRAMA | timeband 
 test   | 06:00 - 08:00
 test2   | 07:00 - 10:00
```

I would like to divide the column like this, according to how many hour we have into the time band, so i need to duplica, triplacte doesnt matter according to to how my hours i have into

```
tv show | timeband 
 test   | 06:00 - 07:00
 test   | 07:00 - 08:00
 test2   | 07:00 - 08:00
 test2   | 08:00 - 09:00
 test2   | 09:00 - 10:00
```

Answer (score 0):

A short [DBIFFLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f995ea8ac0fa769d504b7baaa1a870c)

You should, almost never, combine values in 1 column, like `06:00 - 08:00`. In most situations it is better to keep them split in `06:00` and `08:00`.

```
WITH recursive cte1 AS (
   SELECT 
      n,
      timeband,
      cast(left(timeband,5) as time) fromtime,
      addtime(cast(left(timeband,5) as time),'01:00') totime,
      cast(substring(timeband,9,5) as time) as i
   FROM table1

   union all
   select 
      n,
      timeband,
      addtime(fromtime,'01:00'),
      addtime(totime,'01:00'),
      i
    from cte1 
    where totime< i
   )
SELECT 
  n,
  fromtime,
  totime 
from cte1
order by n,fromtime;
```

output:

| n | fromtime | totime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | 06:00:00 | 07:00:00 |
| test | 07:00:00 | 08:00:00 |
| test2 | 07:00:00 | 08:00:00 |
| test2 | 08:00:00 | 09:00:00 |
| test2 | 09:00:00 | 10:00:00 |

Comment: Thank you for your help @Luuk but there's a problem the field timeband is varchar and it is business rule that the reeason I have the fields like 06:00 - 08:00, there's a way to show only one collum? Or concat the fromtime and fromtime? I'm going to load this select/new table into power bi to connect with another table that has more information and the field I'm going to use to relate is the timeband.

Comment: You can always make 1 field from separate fields. using the SQL function [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: Thank you, I have been running your code for 1 hour now with limit 10 and it is still running, should work like this?

Comment: You never shared info about the table `ibope.tb_audprogramas`. I do not know which indexes exist, and how many records are in that table.   Because there is an `ORDER BY` all results need to be fetched, and ordered before the first 10 can be produced.